# Understand multiple-column index for mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose I need to query:

```
select * from table where f1='f1' and f2='f2' and f3='f3'
```

And I have indexes for `f1_f2` and `f2_f3`, then will my query take advantage of these two indexes? Or I need to create a new index `f1_f2_f3`?

Thanks

Comment: You can try using `EXPLAIN` to examine your query and the index usage.

Comment: If you create an index by `f1_f2_f3` then: #1 - you'll optimize your query completely; #2 - you may remove the index by `f1_f2` because it is obviously excess (the query which needs in it may use newly created index instead). The only exclusion is the case when `f3` is long string/binary column.

Comment: Since all tests are via `=`, the new index can have the columns in any order.  The performance will be virtually the same, regardless of which column you have first in the `INDEX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an index to optimize the search for all three columns in the best way, you'd be better off creating a three-column index on `f1_f2_f3`.

MySQL does have an [index merge algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html), but it doesn't kick in as often as you'd think. Usually the optimizer chooses just one index per table reference. Besides, an index-merge of two index lookups would be less efficient than a single search using one index.

By analogy, suppose you are searching a book using the index at the back of the book. You could look up pages that match one word like "Earth" and that would give you one list of pages to check. Then you look up another index entry for pages that match another word "history" and that would give you a different list of pages. Then you'd have to compare the two lists to find the pages that appear in both lists.

If you had one index entry for "Earth history" that gives only pages that match both words, that would be more optimal.

Comment: Suppose we have index for both `f1` and `f2` and would like to query `where f1='f1' and f2='f2'`. Then the latency approximately proportional to examined rows for `f1` + examined rows for `f2` + comparing/merging these two lists?

Comment: But suppose examined rows for `f1` is 100 while for `f2` is 1000000. Then the query will be greatly slowed down due to `f2`. 
I think more reasonable is based on the already examined 100 rows for `f1`, we start to further filter according to `f2` index (sort of involves merging)

Comment: The latter scenario is what a multi-column index would do.