# Question about adding indexes for multiple columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose I need to sql query like below:

```
select * from table where f1='f1' and f2='f2' and f3='f3'
```

Both `f1` and `f2` are indexed, so filtering `f1` and `f2` should be quick. And now suppose after filtering `f1` and `f2` we only have a few rows (for example 500 rows), then do I still need to add index for `f3`? Would linear scan of these 500 rows be quick enough?

Thanks

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked two days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75925056/understand-multiple-column-index-for-mysql

Comment: Thanks I think slightly different? Rather than asking indexing algorithm, my major question here is if one column doesn't have index, how would that affect overall performance?

Comment: No, you need one index with multiple columns, f1 f2 and f3 for optimal performance.  For example  CREATE INDEX table-ndx-f1f2f3 
ON table(f1,f2,f3);

Comment: The order of columns in the `INDEX` does not matter _for this `SELECT`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way MySQL queries use indexes is to reduce the number of *examined rows*. If a query has to do a linear scan because it couldn't use an index, this will increase the number of examined rows. Examined rows may be eliminated by non-indexed conditions in the query, but the overall performance of the query is roughly proportional to the number of examined rows, not the number that satisfy all the conditions.

How much time it takes to evaluate conditions on the examined rows is highly variable, based on factors such as:

- Whether the page(s) for the given row are in the buffer pool or have to be loaded from storage
- Latency of server resources storage, CPU, and RAM
- Concurrent query load in the MySQL server (the same query may seem a lot slower on a day when traffic is high)
- Concurrent load on the server from other processes

You asked whether the query will be "quick enough" but that's a subjective measure, relative to your own criteria. For example, if your requirements are that the query finish in 500 milliseconds, then it's quick enough if it does finish in 180 milliseconds. It doesn't matter that it's not executing in the most optimal way possible. You haven't stated what your performance requirement is, so only you can know if it's quick enough.